# ERROR: The process "19848" not found while making android build

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project built in angular + ionic. I am trying to built android apk using `ionic cordova build android --verbose` command. Following are my versions
Node - 14.21.3
Python - 2.7

I am able to make web build successfully but while making android build i am facing  `ERROR: The process "19848" not found.`. I don't know why it's trying to do taskkill as i am not even running any other software not either the chrome. Every time i run the same command it's trying to do taskkill with different pid.

I have completed following steps as well

1. Install Android Studio
2. JDK Setup